# Extract Google analytics search keyword and impression

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to extract search engine keywords using **"rga"** package in R.
I'm using the report:
acquisition > search console > queries

However I can't find the right metric name in the api for the search keywords.
I'm trying to find a dimension for eg: ga:searchkeyword, ga:searchenginekeyword etc.

I want to run the following code:

```
    ga$getData(ids, dimensions="ga:xxxxxx", metrics="ga:impressions", 
    start.date="2016-04-01", end.date="2017-04-01")
```

What dimension should I supply in dimensions parameter?

Answer (score 2):

ga:adMatchedQuery just gives you the keywords a user googled before clicking your AdWords-Ad. You will not see the organic Keywords.

You don´t get the organic Keywords from the Search Console with the GA Reporting API.

You can use the package searchConsoleR (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/searchConsoleR/searchConsoleR.pdf) using googleAuthR for the authentication part.

The Query looks like this:

```
keywords <-search_analytics(website_name, 
                             start_date, end_date, 
                             c("query", "page"), 
                             searchType="web")
```

Answer (score 1):

ga:adMatchedQuery is what you're looking for

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=adwords&jump=ga_admatchedquery